# auto declare variable inside condition expression of while in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I have a code that uses a while statement. Inside 
the conditional expression I do a lookup. At the same time the conditional expression checks the return value:

```
#include <map>

struct a {
    a *up;
    std::map<int,int> tbl;
};

void p(a *_a, int id) {
    decltype(_a->tbl)::iterator i;
    while (_a && (i = _a->tbl.find(id)) != _a->tbl.end()) {
        i->second += 1;
        _a = _a->up;
    }
}

int main(int arc, char **argv) {
    a _a1{0,{{0,10},{1,10}}};
    a _a0{&_a1,{{2,11},{3,11}}};
    p(&_a0, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

However I would like to get rid of the explicit declaration of `i`. I would like to use `auto`. In pseudocode:

```
...
void p(a *_a, int id) {
    while (_a && ((auto i = _a->tbl.find(id))) != _a->tbl.end()) {
        i->second += 1;
        _a = _a->up;
    }
}
...
```

Is there a construct in c++11/14/17 that supports this kind of declarations *inside* an expression? Not only `while(auto i = 1) {...}` style declarations? Maybe there are some new features that allow this?

Comment: You can use the new C++17 init, but you still need to update `i`, not sure what is better. It's several lines longer, but you get the assignment out of the condition loop. It would take 10 lines instead of the 4 you have.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher:  it seems that gcc doesnt seem to support init inside while. It support it  when using init in ```if``` . But  ```while (decltype(_a->tbl)::iterator i; _a && ((i = _a->tbl.find(id)) != _a->tbl.end())``` returns an error in gcc 8.2.

Comment: While loops cannot have an init-statement. No compiler is supposed to support that.

Comment: Oh indeed, only `for`and `if`. My bad.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher And `switch`.

Comment: Hopefully one day we will have all ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about separating the two conditions? The main one for the loop to continue is `_a`, and the secondary one (which may always be true) is `_a->tbl.find(id) != _a->tbl.end()`. Return on its negation:

```
void p(a *_a, int id) {
    while (_a) {
        auto i = _a->tbl.find(id);
        if (i == _a->tbl.end()) {
            return;
        }
        i->second += 1;
        _a = _a->up;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was searching for the dense version where I can just add a auto anywhere inside the expression. I guess there is no such construct to get this work.

Comment: @KonradEisele I guess there is not, but even if there was one, I would never use it over a clear separation of the two conditions. Mainly because they don't have the same "priority", if you will.

Comment: I guess it is a matter of taste. Logically both tests are loop-exit-conditons so I 
 would prefer them to reside in the loop condition expression instead of having a ```break``` because the break statement you might need to scroll to see it.

Comment: @KonradEisele I've never had to write something similar with a `break` instead of a `return`. I'm convinced that the kind of situation you have here can always be dealt with cleanly in a relatively short function, in which such a `return` has its place. But of course, I can't prove that.

Comment: You might be right. I wonder weather a future c++ standard will eventually buildin enough type inference so that even ```auto``` will be optional and I can have my ```i``` autodeclared automatically.

Comment: Agreed, nice solution, the assignment is not in the condition and is more readable (and +1 for short functions).